# MS Access queries to select latest dates only

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a database with 2 tables and I'm trying to build a simple query to return the latest cost of each Item.

Sample:

> ID, Name, Cost, Effective Date
>
> 1...Item1...5...7/1/16
>
> 2...Item1...4...6/1/16
>
> 3...Item2...6...8/1/16
>
> 4...Item1...2...9/1/16

Should return only lines 3 (Item2) and 4 (Item1's latest).

Using Access interface, I've managed to get it working only if I don't include cost at all, and I can't remove cost from the `GROUP BY` line without Access freaking out. Any help is appreciated!

SQL View:

```
SELECT Item.Item_ID, Item.Item_Name, Rate_Changes.Cost, Max(Rate_Changes.Effective_Date) As MaxOfEffective_Date
FROM Item INNER JOIN Rate_Changes ON Item.Item_ID = Rate_Changes.Item_ID
WHERE Item.Active=True
GROUP BY Item.Item_ID, Item.Active, Item.Item_Name,
Rate_Changes.Cost, Rate_Changes.Effective_Date
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
SELECT i.Item_ID, i.Item_Name, rc.Cost, rc.Effective_Date
FROM Item as i INNER JOIN
     Rate_Changes as rc
     ON i.Item_ID = rc.Item_ID
WHERE i.Active = True AND
      rc.Effective_Date = (SELECT MAX(rc2.Effective_Date)
                           FROM Rate_Changes as rc2
                           WHERE rc2.Item_Id = i.Item_id
                          );
```

This assumes that there are no duplicate effective dates for a given item.

EDIT:

If you do have duplicates, you can do:

```
SELECT i.Item_ID, i.Item_Name, rc.Cost, rc.Effective_Date
FROM Item as i INNER JOIN
     Rate_Changes as rc
     ON i.Item_ID = rc.Item_ID
WHERE i.Active = True AND
      rc.Effective_Date = (SELECT TOP 1 rc2.Effective_Date
                           FROM Rate_Changes as rc2
                           WHERE rc2.Item_Id = i.Item_id
                           ORDER BY rc2.Effective_Date DESC, rc2.id DESC
                          );
```

Comment: That works fine from my limited sample data, thanks! I'm pretty sure there should never be duplicate effective dates for a given item - is there any way to enforce this? I'm practically completely new to access, so I'm still fumbling about with the commands.

Comment: @rgdhndho . . . If the `id` increases along with the date, then you can use `id` instead of `effective_date`.

Comment: The ID is the primary key, so it's definitely unique. I'm not quite sure what you mean however; I want to have the query show the latest price (max effective date) for each item ID. How can the ID (primary key for the Rate_Change table) be used to group? I tried your alternative code and it ended up with a warning that the query returns at most one result. I just threw <code>Order By rc.Item_ID</code> to the end instead and it's working fine from what I can tell. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: The ID is the primary key, so it's definitely unique. I'm not quite sure what you mean however; I want to have the query show the latest price (max effective date) for each item ID. How can the ID (primary key for the Rate_Change table) be used to group? I tried your alternative code and it ended up with a warning that the query returns at most one result. I just threw <code>Order By rc.Item_ID</code> to the end instead and it's working fine from what I can tell. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: The edited version should work even if there are duplciates.